# Where does CSVHelper determine the Type Converter to use for a property?

Tags: csvhelper

I'm trying to understand how `CsvHelper` sets the TypeConverter for a property in a given `MemberMap`.

Given this code:

```
public MyMapper : ClassMap<Client>
{
    public MyMapper()
    {
       Map(c => c.Age).Name("C_AGE");
       ...
    }
 }
```

I'm not specifying the `Type Converter` to use so somewhere along the line, CsvHelper has to be looking at the `Age` property of `Client` and determining that it is an `int` and that it should convert the CSV value to an int using the `Int32Converter`.  **Where is it making this determination?**

I've browsed the code some on GitHub but haven't been able to locate where this takes place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to your question is that the defaults for each type are created in `TypeConverterCache`.

```cs
private void CreateDefaultConverters()
{
    AddConverter(typeof(bool), new BooleanConverter());
    AddConverter(typeof(byte), new ByteConverter());
    AddConverter(typeof(byte[]), new ByteArrayConverter());
    AddConverter(typeof(char), new CharConverter());
    AddConverter(typeof(DateTime), new DateTimeConverter());
    AddConverter(typeof(DateTimeOffset), new DateTimeOffsetConverter());
    AddConverter(typeof(decimal), new DecimalConverter());
    AddConverter(typeof(double), new DoubleConverter());
    AddConverter(typeof(float), new SingleConverter());
    AddConverter(typeof(Guid), new GuidConverter());
    AddConverter(typeof(short), new Int16Converter());
    AddConverter(typeof(int), new Int32Converter());
    AddConverter(typeof(long), new Int64Converter());
    AddConverter(typeof(sbyte), new SByteConverter());
    AddConverter(typeof(string), new StringConverter());
    AddConverter(typeof(TimeSpan), new TimeSpanConverter());
    AddConverter(typeof(ushort), new UInt16Converter());
    AddConverter(typeof(uint), new UInt32Converter());
    AddConverter(typeof(ulong), new UInt64Converter());
    AddConverter(typeof(IList), new IEnumerableConverter());
    AddConverter(typeof(ICollection), new IEnumerableConverter());
    AddConverter(typeof(IEnumerable), new IEnumerableConverter());
    AddConverter(typeof(IDictionary), new IDictionaryConverter());
}
```